# Python discrete optimization with linear objective function

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I have some points(N). For these points I have a distance matrix D (N*N). Also I have an attribute data for these points A (1*N). I want to select fixed number of points(K) such that `sum of attribute is maximum` while distance between selected points lies between a range (min_dis,max_dis).

I tried implementing this optimization problem in Pulp with N=10,K=3.

`A = [300,436,234,11,23,897,439,56,123,432]`.

```
    import pulp
    import numpy as np

    inds = range(10)

    #create a vector x which will only accept value 0,1
    x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('x', inds, lowBound = 0,upBound = 1,cat = pulp.LpInteger)

    my_lp_problem = pulp.LpProblem("My LP Problem", pulp.LpMaximize)

    #sum of x should be equal to no of points I want (which is 3)
    my_lp_problem += sum([x[store] for store in inds]) == 3

    #maximize dot product A.x (which would be sum of attributes)
    my_lp_problem += sum([A[point] * x[point] for point in inds])
```

However I am not able to put the constraints on distance matrix. Which would be something like this:

```
    np.multiply(x,D).max() < max_dis and np.multiply(x,D).min() > min_dis
```

As I could not find how to use max(), min() and matrix multiplication kind of things in pulp. What I understand is this has a linear objective function while the constraints are not linear. I also explored `scipy.optimize` but as x can contain only 0 and 1 not a continuous variable I started with pulp. 
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any non-linearities here. If i understood the task correctly, you could:

- introduce **aux-vars** `P[i,j] in {0,1}`

  - *point i selected* (let's assume: `S[i] = 1`) & *point j selected* *IMPLIES* `P[i,j] = 1`
  - removing symmetries, this set is of size `C(N,2)`
  - you can interpret it as *active pair indicator*
- formulate the above relation:

  - `P[i,j] >= S[i] + S[j] - 1` (for all i; for all j)
  - warning: we are only formulating the implication (not equivalence); not necessarily interested in the other direction
- add a bounding-constraint for all C(N,2) distances (equivalent to bounding the max value; common reformulation):

  - `P[i,j] * DIST[i,j] <= max-dist` (for all i; for all j)
  - this is an affine-constraint (DIST & max-dist are constants)

Remark: the above is somewhat informal in regards to the dimensionality of P (flat 1D vs. 2D) and *for all i; for all j*. The details depend on this decision and if symmetries are removed.

Comment: THanks for the quick answer. What is S?

Comment: The binary-variable which indicates that some point is selected. Maybe your ```x```? The general idea is just: we don't need to enforce all possible distance constraints, but those, where both points in the D-matrix are selected. Therefore the partial AND-linearization (only one direction).

Comment: Yes I was also trying to avoid all possible distance constraints as at a time only K points will be selected so only C(K,2) distances should be looked upon. I was not able to get proper formulation. Where is the constraints that only K points will be selected??

Comment: Not there. The above is just for the distance-constraint. Without lazy-constraints (and advanced solver support) i somewhat recommend the above: just add all pairwise constraints (where some are active; some are not).